# How to execute page.render inside page.evaluate?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I do want to render my page and exit PhantomJS in the evaluate function, because I want to trigger it when a specific event is fired.

I've tried something like this:

```
page.evaluate(page, function (page, phantom) {

    //do some stuff on my page

    //i want to execute this in an eventhandler of my page though thats not the problem
    page.render('imgName.png'); 
    page.render('pdfName.pdf');
    phantom.exit();

}, page, phantom);
```

This doesn't work in my example, because `page.render` seems to be undefined. Maybe there is a serializer for the arguments which is not serializing functions of the obj?

Is this even possible? Does anyone know a solution for my issue?

I know I could set a while loop in my evaluate function and prevent its termination and do this page render stuff outside afterwards. I don't like this though.

Comment: Great question and great answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`page.evaluate()` is sandboxed. The function that you pass in is evaluated in the page context and all arguments need to be serializable in order the be successfully passed in. You cannot pass `page` or `phantom` into page context. The [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) say the following:

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

This is what [`page.onCallback`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html) is for:

```
page.onCallback = function(data){
    if (data.exit) {
        page.render('imgName.png'); 
        page.render('pdfName.pdf');
        phantom.exit();
    }
};
page.evaluate(page, function () {
    //do some stuff on my page

    //i want to execute this in an eventhandler of my page though thats not the problem
    window.callPhantom({ exit: true });
});
```