# Does PhantomJS share memory between multiple requests?

Tags: d3.js, phantomjs

I'm using [PhantomJS + d3](https://github.com/subramanya2107/d3js-phantomjs-demo) to render a map of US Zipcodes as a backend process. The rendering and zip code counting takes long enough that putting the html and d3 js in the browser would require a minute to load and caused other issues, so we moved it to the backend.

If I send one request via curl to the node server that PhantomJS starts up, no problem. If I space our multiple map requests by about 15 seconds in between, also no problem. However, if I launch a couple curl requests very quickly, the rendered images wind up looking the same (aka the same image is written to multiple files.) Here is the phantom script:

var port,
        server,
        service,
        page,
        url,
        svgDrawer;

```
fs     = require('fs');
port   = 9494;
server = require('webserver').create();
page   = require('webpage').create();

service = server.listen(port, function (request, response) {
    var drawerPayload = null;
    try{
        drawerPayload=JSON.parse(request.post);
    } catch(e){
        response.statusCode = 417;
        response.write("Error : Invalid Input JSON");
        response.close();
        return;
    }

    url = 'file:///' + fs.absolute('./'+drawerPayload.inFile);
    page.open(url, function (status) {
        if(status=="success"){
            page.evaluate(function(data){
                $("body").on( "click", data, chartBuilder );
                $("body").click();

                var maxtimeOutMillis = 15000,
                    start = new Date().getTime(),
                    condition = false,
                    interval = setInterval(function() {
                        if ( (new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition ) {
                            condition = $("svg.chart").hasClass("done"); //< defensive code
                        } else {
                            if(!condition) {
                                clearInterval(interval)
                            } else {
                                page.render(drawerPayload.outFile);
                                clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                            }
                        }
                    }, 250); //< repeat check every 250ms
            });

            response.statusCode = 200;
        } else {
            response.statusCode = 404;
            response.write("Not Found"+url);
        }
        response.close();
        return;
    });

    page.onError = function (msg, trace) {
        console.log(msg);
        trace.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log('  ', item.file, ':', item.line);
        })
        response.statusCode = 417;
        response.write("Error : "+msg);
        response.close();
        return;
    }
});
```

and the html+d3 looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.zip {
    stroke: none;
}
.chart {
    fill: white;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div id="chart-container">
        <svg class="chart"></svg>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="./jquery-min.js"></script>
<script src="./d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

function chartBuilder(e){
    var zip_data = e.data;
    $.getJSON("zips_us_topo.json", function(us){
        console.log("rendering...\n");
        var width = 1000;
        var height = 500;
        var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
            .scale(width)
            .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

        var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
        var color = d3.scale.log().domain([1,zip_data.max+1]).range(["#cccccc","#f63337"]);

        var svg = d3.select("svg.chart")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .style({margin: "10px 100px"})
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "counties")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.zip_codes_for_the_usa).features)
            .enter()
                .append("path")
                    .attr("class", "zip")
                    .style({fill: function(d){
                        return color(zip_data.counts[d.properties.zip] ? zip_data.counts[d.properties.zip]+1 : 1);
                    }})
                    .attr("d", path);
        svg.classed("done", true);
    });
}
</script>
```

If the requests are all curled at the same time, it looks like it's writing one image to all of the output files. Does PhantomJS create a new page for each request, or is it loading the same request each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only a single `page` instance for all requests that come. This might create some race conditions when new requests come in and hijack the current `page.open()` request. There are basically two ways to solve this depending on your preferred scenario.

#### Multiple "tabs"

The simple fix would be to create a new `page` instance for every request and they will be essentially different tabs in the same browser. So if cookies or localStorage is an issue, this is not for you.

Move `page = require('webpage').create();` inside the `server.listen` callback and don't forget to [`close()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/close.html) the `page` instance after use.

#### Only one request at a time

Since this is a not so short running process, you can start a `page.open()` when it is not currently running and put all incoming requests into a queue as long as `page.open()` hasn't finished. After it is finished, save the response, go through the request queue and respond with the same response to all of them.

This is of course much nicer on memory consumption than the first solution if there really are many concurrent requests.

---

There are other problems with your code though. You use `setInterval()` inside `page.evaluate()`, which breaks off of the control flow. `response.statusCode = 200;` will be most likely set before the page is rendered.

That `page.render()` inside of `page.evaluate()` is the other problem. `page.evaluate()` is the sandboxed page context. It doesn't have access to variables defined outside of it and that includes `page` and `require`. ([Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26162627/1816580) for this isolated problem)

Those two problems can be solved with a single blow by waiting outside of the page context for a render condition inside of it. I suggest using [`waitFor` from the examples](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js):

```
if(status=="success"){
    page.evaluate(function(data){
        window._finishIndicationVariable = false;
        $("body").on( "click", data, chartBuilder );
        $("body").click();

        var maxtimeOutMillis = 15000,
            start = new Date().getTime(),
            condition = false,
            interval = setInterval(function() {
                if ( (new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition ) {
                    condition = $("svg.chart").hasClass("done"); //< defensive code
                } else {
                    if(!condition) {
                        clearInterval(interval)
                    } else {
                        window._finishIndicationVariable = true;
                        clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                    }
                }
            }, 250); //< repeat check every 250ms
    });
    waitFor(function check(){
        return page.evaluate(function(){
            return window._finishIndicationVariable;
        });
    }, function onReady(){
        page.render(drawerPayload.outFile);
        response.statusCode = 200;
        response.close();
    });
} else {
    response.statusCode = 404;
    response.write("Not Found"+url);
    response.close();
}
```

Note that `response.close();` is used two times, because one of the if branches is asynchronous and the one is not.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it's going in the correct direction. It raises a problem though -- without page in the global scope, I can longer call page.render inside of page.evaluate. Can you help with that?

Comment: I missed that part. It's impossible to call `page.render()` inside of `page.evaluate()` regardless where `page` is defined. I only found a CasperJS example, but it is the same thing: [A: Use casper function inside casper.evaluate()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28763952/1816580)

Comment: Yeah, I just found that: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html. How can I wait for the page to finish evaluating before rendering the page? Should I just have a timeout?

Comment: You're already using a [`waitFor`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js)-like function to wait for a condition inside of the page context, so you can use a similar function until the inner function is finished. I'll extend my answer.